# Why these two functions does not behave the same

Tags: c++

For empty vector Fun1 returns 0. Function Fun2, which should be equivalent to Fun1 (only one small change, see below), crashes with error vector subscript out of range. Any ideas why is that?
Code run in Visual Studio 2017

```
int Fun1(vector<int> service_times) {
    sort(service_times.begin(), service_times.end());
    int sum = 0;
    int sumi = 0;
    int st = service_times.size() - 1;//condition stired in variable
    for (int i = 0; i < st; i++)
    {
        sumi += service_times[i];
        sum = sum + sumi;

    }
    return sum;
}


int Fun2(vector<int> service_times) {
    sort(service_times.begin(), service_times.end());
    int sum = 0;
    int sumi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (service_times.size() - 1); i++)//condition 
                                                         //directly written 
    {
        sumi += service_times[i];
        sum = sum + sumi;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How did you create the vectors and how do you call the functions?

Comment: Is the vector empty? Why do you subtract one?

Comment: The types are different between your functions. `service_times.size()` does not return an `int`, so storing it in `int st` performs a conversion, which affects the way the loop works.

Comment: @melpomene, what conversion would that be other than truncating the value? Also OP mentions the vectors are supposed to be empty

Comment: @smac89 One from an `unsigned` to a `signed` integer type. Guess what happens if you do `0 - 1` in unsigned integer arithmetic.

Comment: @melpomene, bingo! That's it

Comment: For future reference, I believe `-Wall` would warn about this, in gcc at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `service_times` is an empty vector, `service_times.size()` ought to return `0`, no?

**No.** It returns `size_t(0)`, which is an unsigned type. Therefore, `service_times.size() - 1` is a `unsigned - signed` operation, where the `signed` value (`1`) is "promoted" to `unsigned` type. Therefore, `0 - 1` is actually `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

In the first function, you saved it by storing it again in an `int` variable: it becomes `-1` again. Therefore, `i < st` is `i < -1`, which worked incidentally. However, in the second function, `i < st` is actually `i < <some ultra big value>`, which, LOL.